# ListIterator or Iterator does not stop at the end of the List

Tags: java, selenium, iterator, webdriver

I am storring the multiple elements (17 to be specific) into List. and I am trying to iterate through it and print something. But When I checked, the iterator `.hasNext()` is not stopping at the end of the List.

```
List<WebElement> Categories = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//h2[@class='popover-category-name']"));

ListIterator<WebElement> ele = Categories.listIterator();
int i=0;
while(ele.hasNext()) {
    //String eleText = Categories.get(i).getText();
    System.out.println("Element at position "+i+" ");
    i++;
}
```

Output is coming like this.

...

Element at position 1329908

Element at position 1329909

Element at position 1329910

Element at position 1329911

Element at position 1329912

Element at position 1329913

Comment: you do not consume elements from iterator by calling `next` so `hasNext` is always true.

Comment: [next](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#next()) *Returns the next element in the list and advances the cursor position.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you do not consume the elements from iterator - the cursor for this iterator is not moved and `hasNext` is always true. You should call `ListIterator::next` in your loop :

```
ListIterator<WebElement> ele = Categories.listIterator();
while(ele.hasNext()) {
    WebElement element = ele.next();
    // do something with your element
}
```

From [`ListIterator::next`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ListIterator.html#next()) docs :

> Returns the next element in the list **and advances the cursor position.**

Comment: Thanks for the Explanation ! Understood and Worked.